# hibernate rollback removing oracle records

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I'm getting the following exception:

`Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1`

I know that this exception usually occurs when there is no such data in the database. However, whenever this exception occurs, all of my records from my Oracle table are deleted.

I'm suspecting that it is the hibernate rollback removing all records but I cannot pinpoint what is really causing this behavior. Any help/lead would be appreciated. I'm using hibernate4 + spring + oracle10.

Comment: Under what context is this happening?  What SQL are you performing?  If you do a bunch of inserts and get an error, then they are probably being rolled back.

Comment: This exception can happen in many situations. If you can show your mapping file and usage code it will be easier to know what is happening? Also hibernate would not go and delete existing records unless you are saying so.

Comment: thanks for comments. i'm just (trying to) update existing single record in oracle via hibernate update query. i somehow fixed it and no longer see this issue, but i still haven't found the cause yet. if it happens again, i will provide more info.